# Is this edit correct or does it change too much of the question?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I recently answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23532153/3155705), which was originally [poorly worded and difficult to understand](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23532153/2). After the OP outlined their goals in the comments, I managed to provide an answer which they later accepted. Subsequently, I suggested [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4764569) in an attempt to clarify the question and perhaps help future users.

The edit received some rejections claiming that my edit changes too much in the question and the original meaning is lost. Although it was ultimately accepted, the reviewers who accepted it look more like robo-reviewers than those who rejected it.

Therefore, I would like to ask for your opinions. Is my edit correct and valid, or do you think that it changed too much in the post and it should've been rejected? If my edit is good, is there anything I could've done to make it seem less like I changed too much?

PS: The link to the OP's comment (in the edit summary) is now broken, [here's the new link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532153/choose-where-to-save-a-file-during-runtime#comment36099978_23532153).

The text of the comment is,

> Click a button --> open new txt file with my text --> save it a place where I want

Comment: It does change a significant amount of text, and in a way that is somewhat incongruent with the original wording. Honestly, at a glance it looked like an audit. That being said I would have approved it, and I reject 70% of suggested edits.

Comment: @CarlVeazey I agree that I've changed the wording quite significantly; I'll definitely try to make an effort to make it sound more similar in the future. And yes, I previously have had [another edit rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4153466) because it looked like an audit.

Comment: To be clear I think you did a great job I'm just speculating that others may have gotten spooked by the drastic change in wording

Comment: Saying "as per OP's comment" (and linking to OP's comment), **as you did**, makes it a winner in my opinion. That's the crucial thing if you're changing meaning.

Comment: Yet it's still *"put on hold as too broad"* four hours ago?

Comment: I've made bigger edits myself (particularly on SO and Christianity SE; also on a few other sites). I think this one was perfect. I agree with @LeonBambrick that the link to the comment in the edit reason is the deciding factor.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is a substantial edit, but it does remarkably clarify the intentions of the OP. So, kudos for the effort to salvage the question!

The only caveat I might have is that the post now uses a keyword that the OP doesn't necessarily understand (*runtime*). This could potentially make the question *less* useful to people of the same skill/language level.

Comment: Besides, it's not just an opinion. This answer does provide a constructive criticism in the second paragraph.

Answer (score 9):

In my opinion your edit is appropriate and I'm sure it helped the author of the question.

Instead of getting downvoted there are now people willing to help him, as **you've made it more clear** what exactly he is asking. Your edit surely helped out, so it is correct in my opinion.

Answer (score 7):

Personally, and I know this is opinionated, I do agree on the edit. On the other hand, I think even after the edit, that the question is too broad, probably because of the lack of understanding by the user. So - again personally (thank god this is Meta) - I would have simply left it alone. Or, as I've currently done, close it for being too broad.

Generally, if you answer these kind of questions, you get an additional bonus question or 10 from the user. If you are really unlucky, you won't get an accept from a user either because you did not answer #10 in the list.

Comment: How is the question too broad? I would've thought the revised question is specific enough for SO's standards, but I'm still quite new to the community.

Answer (score 7):

Usually, you should not make radical changes like this. But when the original post is of awful quality, as in this case, you only have two options: attempt to salvage something from it or close it down.

Attempting to salvage rather than closing is more useful to the OP, so the OP will certainly prefer that option. So the edit in itself is fine.

But on the other hand, if you keep giving fish to lazy crap-posters, they will just come back and beg for more fish each time they are hungry. In the long term, it is better to teach them how to fish themselves, by down-voting and closing bad posts. We shouldn't have to read people's mind each time they ask a question.

Comment: "In the long term, it is better to teach them how to fish themselves, by down-voting and closing bad posts." While that may be true, I have to respectfully disagree. **In my opinion**, downvoting and closing does not teach the users much, if at all. Rather, it will just cause the user to get more frustrated (and perhaps post another crap question HOW DO I DO DIS PLS DONT CLOSE HELPPPPP). Editing would teach the user how to write better questions and *help future users*, which seems to be far more beneficial to me.

Comment: @JWLim If you are a sensible person and your question gets closed, you would probably try to figure out what you did wrong. Either by reading the "how to post" links shown to you when the question gets closed, or by finding your way there yourself by clicking "help". If you do neither of this but keeps posting crap, chances are you're a hopeless case that will not benefit the community. If you do try to improve after reading the "how to post", but still don't manage, it suggests that the "how to post" information needs improvement (which I doubt).

Comment: The true reason why we see the quality of SO dropping right now, is all the super-helpful people trying to teach even the most hopeless cases, who in turn just want a solution to their specific problem, with minimum effort. They don't want to get taught anything. They don't want to contribute to SO. So how is any kind of interaction with them beneficial for the site? Also I really don't see how editing posts will help future users. If your post gets closed, what are the chances you start digging through random old posts to see what you did wrong?

Comment: @Lundin It helps future users of the "Hey, i have this problem where i try to save my file to a location i specify at runtime, guess i should search SO with related keywords."-kind. What as far as i understand the purpose of SO, are exactly the users we want to help.

Answer (score 3):

In context, and with the knowledge that the original poster meant "text file" when he wrote "Notepad", your edit is valid and an excellent edit.

I must say, however, that had I been reviewing it, I would likely have rejected it as "too radical" just like the two actual rejections.  The reason is that changing "Notepad" to "text file" seems like a major change in meaning, for those of us who know that Notepad is an application, not a file type.  My hypothetical rejection, and I suspect the two actual rejections, would have been for this reason and not because of any of the rest of the edit.

I think this is just one of the rare cases where the edit review interface facilitates the wrong answer.  I don't think it comes up often enough to worry about, and once you can edit without approval, you won't have to worry about it at all, since you actually were very careful with the edit.  Until then, if anything like this gets rejected, you could suggest that the original poster edit his question, since the original poster can always edit without review.

Answer (score -8):

Your edit is substantial, and thus risked being rejected.  Perhaps you could have edited less of the post and improved it just as much.

For example, you could have left the code alone entirely.  There were meaningless edits there.

Comment: Removing a single space of indentation is not really a reason for rejection, is it?

Comment: It shouldn't be, but it also isn't necessary for understanding or any other reason.

Comment: I did leave the code alone, save for the additional and unneeded space. To me, it improves the formatting by a tiny bit, although I am known to nitpick at times. Anyway, I appreciate your feedback. Is there anything else that you think I should've left alone?

Comment: @JWLim Perhaps you could have kept more words from the author, but really, your edit seems appropriate.  My point of the code edit is that seeing the additional changed lines in the post, especially in a code section, makes the edit look more radical than it is.